# task is to print a string excluding character "a" which preceding characters of the input

Tags: python, python-3.x

The task is to take a string as input from the user.

And then print a list which is the preceding characters of the input and does not including "a".
expected output :

1)print input string

2)print output list of preceding characters of the input string excluding `"a"`.

using python we should print a list of characters from the string input of the user which should exclude the character "a" from list.
if input string is apple
the output should be `['o','o','k','d']`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
d=dict(zip([chr(x) for x in range(98,123)],[chr(x) for x in range(97,123)]))
# {'b': 'a', 'c': 'b', 'd': 'c', 'e': 'd', 'f': 'e', 'g': 'f', 'h': 'g', 'i': 'h', 'j': 'i', 'k': 'j', 'l': 'k', 'm': 'l', 'n': 'm', 'o': 'n', 'p': 'o', 'q': 'p', 'r': 'q', 's': 'r', 't': 's', 'u': 't', 'v': 'u', 'w': 'v', 'x': 'w', 'y': 'x', 'z': 'y'}
​
l=[]
s='apple'
for x in s:
    if x=='a':
        pass
    else:
        l.append(d[x])
print(l)
#['o', 'o', 'k', 'd']
```